# Send Email in a Rails App Without using a Database Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am relatively new to Rails. I have created a simple app, using Ruby 2.5 & Rails 5.2, that will send an email to an admin when a website visitor requests some information. The app does not use a database, because none of the visitor's information is to be saved or stored, therefore ActiveRecord is not used. Just need to get some information from the visitor via a form and email it. Research suggests using ActiveModel instead but I still can't get it to work. No 3rd party mailing apps needed. What am I overlooking? Model, Controller, Views, Mailer code appear below.

```
    #Model: Visitor.rb
    class Visitor
        include ActiveModel::Model
        include ActiveModel::Conversion
        extend ActiveModel::Naming
        include ActiveModel::Validations

        attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :phone, :email, :interest

        # Validations & Requirements
        validates :fname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
        validates :lname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
        validates :lname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
        VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
        validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
        validates :interest, presence: true

        def initialize(fname, lname, phone, email, interest)
            @fname = fname
            @lname = lname
            @phone = phone
            @email = email
            @interest = interest

            post_initialize
       end

       # #make in lieu of #create
       def self.make(fname, lname, phone, email, interest)
           attributes = {fname: fname, lname: lname, phone: phone, email: email, interest: interest}
           object = new(attributes)
           object.save
           @visitor = object
           @visitor
       end

      def persisted?
          false
      end

      def send_mail
          # Following method defined in NotifierMailer
          NotifierMailer.visitor_info(self).deliver_now
      end


      private

      def post_initialize
          if email
              email.downcase
          end
      end
    end

    # Controller: Visitors_controller.rb
    class VisitorsController < ApplicationController

        def new
            @Visitor = Visitor.new
        end

       def make
           @visitor = Visitor.new(visitor_params)
           if @visitor.valid?
               @visitor.send_mail # Instance method in Guest model
               flash[:notice] = "Your request has been sent! Thank you for contacting us."
               redirect_to welcome_path
           else
               render 'new'
           end
       end

       private

       def visitor_params
           params.require(:visitor).permit(:fname, :lname, :phone, :email, :interest)
       end
    end

    # Routes: Routes.rb
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
        get 'favicon', to: 'pages#favicon'

        root to: 'pages#index', as: 'welcome'

        # ... other routes for static page navigation

        get '/reqinfo', to: 'visitors#new'

        post '/reqinfo', to: 'visitors#make'
    end

    # View: New.html.erb
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <%= form_with model: @visitor, url: reqinfo_path, local: true do |form| %>
                <%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: form.object %>
                <%= form.label 'First Name' %>
                <%= form.text_field :fname, class: 'form-control' %>
                <%= form.label 'Last Name' %>
                <%= form.text_field :lname, class: 'form-control' %>
                <%= form.label :phone %>
                <%= form.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
                <%= form.label 'Email Address' %>
                <%= form.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
                <%= form.label 'Interest' %>
                <%= form.text_field :interest, class 'form-control' %>
                <%= form.submit 'Submit', id: "button" %>
            <% end %><!-- form_with -->
        </div><!-- col-md6-3 -->
    </div><!-- row -->

     # Mailer: Notifier_mailer.rb
     class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
         default from: 'noreply@thecompany.com'
         def guest_info(visitor)
             @visitor = visitor
             mail(to: 'admin@thecompany.com', subject: "Website Visitors Request for Information")
        end
     end

     # Message: Visitor_info.html.erb
     <h1>Dear Admin;</h1>
     <br>
     <% timestamp = Time.now %>
     <p>
         <%= visitor.fname %> <%= @visitor.lname %> visited the TheCompany website on <%= timestamp.localtime %>. He/she is requesting information regarding a <%= @visitor.interest %>. Their contact information phone: <%= @visitor.phone %> and email: <%= @visitor.email %>
     </p>
```

Comment: It is better to include some logs that explain about `still can't get it to work`.
Your code looks good, so I guess that you mean cannot receive the email at `admin@thecompany.com`  
It is simply that you can go into the `rails console` then `visitor = Visitor.new; NotifierMailer.visitor_info(visitor).deliver_now` and see the logs of ActionMailer print out. I believe that your trouble just comes from a wrong configuration of ActionMailer.

Comment: Please be more specific, as "it doesn't work", it's hard to help otherwise. Where does it fail, what do the logs say, have you made sure, mails are sent somewhere in your development environment?

Comment: Thanks. yeuem1vannam suggestion worked.